# how to put legend label on the left hand side of legend form

Tags: android, legend, mpandroidchart

I have a graph in my app that is drawn using MPAndroid .
The problem is : how to put legend label on the left hand side of the legend form ? The below picture shows my problem
[image]

I want to put legend forms (circles)  on the right hand side of the legend label

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy:

```
legend.setDirection(Legend.LegendDirection.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
```

Try this code..

Comment: yeap, that's it
is there any way to set marginRight of legend label?

Comment: @farshid83 Of course, if you already set the direction is from right to left, then  `legend.setFormToTextSpace(50f)`  can set the marginRight of the label.

Comment: well, I mean legend label (and its text together)  margin from the right of the graph, setFormTextSpace method is the space between text and label. I don't want to change the space between text and label

Comment: @farshid83 try to use `legend.setXOffset(-20f);`